# Prove that: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin^2(x) + 1} = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, trigonometry

Prove

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin^2(x) + 1} = 0$$

---

**The proof:**

Let $$|x| \le 1 \implies -1 \le x \le 1$$

$$\displaystyle \frac{|x|}{|\sin^2(x) + 1|} < \epsilon\text{ for }\displaystyle |x| < \delta$$

$$-1 \le x \le 1
\\\implies \sin(-1) \le \sin(x) \le \sin(1) \implies -\sin(1) \le \sin(x) \le \sin(1)
\\\implies \sin^2(1) \le \sin^2(x) \le \sin^2(1) \implies |\sin^2(x) + 1| = |\sin^2(1) + 1| \implies \displaystyle |\frac{1}{\sin^2(x) + 1}| = |\frac{1}{\sin^2(1) + 1}|$$

(1) $$|x| < \delta_1$$

(2) $$\displaystyle |\frac{1}{\sin^2(x) + 1}| = |\frac{1}{\sin^2(1) + 1}|$$

(3) $$\displaystyle \frac{|x|}{|\sin^2(x) + 1|} < \frac{\delta_1}{|\sin^2(1) + 1|}$$

(4) $$\displaystyle \frac{|\delta_1|}{|\sin^2(1) + 1|} = \epsilon \implies \delta_1 = (|\sin^2(1) + 1|)(\epsilon) $$

Finally, $\delta = \min(1, (|\sin^2(1) + 1|)(\epsilon)) \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \blacksquare$

Thoughts?

### **EDIT:**

The original proof was indeed terrible, here's a new approach.

Let $|x| < 1 \implies -1 < x < 1$

$\sin^2(-1) + 1 < \sin^2(x) + 1 <\sin^2(1) + 2$

$\implies \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sin^2(-1) + 1} > \frac{1}{\sin^2(x) + 1} > \frac{1}{\sin^2(1) + 1}$

$\implies \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sin^2(-1) + 1} > \frac{1}{\sin^2(x) + 1} \implies \frac{1}{|\sin^2(-1) + 1|} > \frac{1}{|\sin^2(x) + 1|} \implies  \frac{1}{|\sin^2(x) + 1|} < \frac{1} {|\sin^2(-1) + 1|} $

$(1) |x| < \delta_1$

$(2) \displaystyle \frac{1}{|\sin^2(x) + 1|} < \frac{1} {|\sin^2(-1) + 1|}$

$(3) \displaystyle \frac{|x|}{|\sin^2(x) + 1|} < \frac{\delta_1} {|\sin^2(-1) + 1|}$

Finally,

$\epsilon(\sin^2(-1) + 1) = \delta_1$

Therefore,

$\delta = \min(1,\epsilon \cdot (\sin^2(-1) + 1)) \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \blacksquare$

Comment: You can't get to $\sin^2(1) \le \sin^2(x)$ from your start.

Comment: $a \leq b$ do not implies $a^2 \leq b^2$... take $a = -2, b = 1$ and your inequality $\sin^2 (1)\leq \sin^2(x) \leq \sin^2(1)$ implies $\sin^2(x)=\sin(1)$ which is obviously not always true for $|x| \leq 1$.

Comment: there should probably be an explanation to $-1<x<1 \implies -\sin 1 \le \sin x \le \sin 1$.

Comment: Okay. $-1 < x < 1$ therefore $sin(-1) < sin(x) < sin(1)$ but realize $sin(-1) = -sin(1)$ then square and proceed

Comment: @Amad27 you should invoke the fact that $\sin$ increases. on which interval does it?

Comment: You cannot square an inequality when one or both of the sides are negative! $-\sin(1) \leq \sin(x)$ does not imply $\sin^2(1) \leq \sin^2(x)$ (try $x=0$)! The proof has many mistakes and is way to long and complicated. mookids answer below is the way to go here.

Comment: Can somebody recheck my "edit" answer?

Comment: @Amad27 why not just use the answer below with the most up votes? It's cleaner,clearer,  and more intuitive.

Comment: @Pubbie, because I am trying to explore methods.

Answer (score 11):

This is way too complicated, don't you think?

Why not just say that
$$
\left| \frac{x}{1+\sin^2 x}
\right| \le |x| \le \epsilon
$$
as
 soon as $|x|<\delta = \epsilon$?

Comment: I just want to know if my approach is correct

Comment: there seem to be some things not right. just look at the comments under your question.

Comment: What is wrong? I gave a comment to your there as well

Answer (score 8):

**Remarks on your new approach**

Since in your attempt, $x\in[-1, 1]$, lets try $x=0$ 
$$ \sin^2(-1)+1\lt \sin^2(0)+1 $$
$$ \sin^2(-1)\lt \sin^2(0) $$
$$ \sin^2(1)\lt 0 $$
Is this correct to you? Also if you wish to start from $|x|$, then why not start with the fact that
$$ 
|x|\le |x|\left|\sin^2(x)+1\right|
$$
$$ 
\frac{|x|}{\left|\sin^2(x)+1\right|}\le |x|
$$

**Method 1**

Unless your forced to use the definition of the limit, we could simply show that
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin^2(x)+1} =\frac{0}{\sin^2(0)+1} = \frac{0}{0+1} = \frac{0}{1} = 0$$
**Method 2**

If the other answer isn't obvious to you, here's another way to see it. First note that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$ 0\le\sin^2(x) $$
$$ 1\le\sin^2(x)+1 $$
$$ 1\le\left|\sin^2(x)+1\right| $$
$$ \frac{1}{\left|\sin^2(x)+1\right|}\le 1 $$
$$ \frac{|x|}{\left|\sin^2(x)+1\right|}\le |x| $$
$$ \left|\frac{x}{\sin^2(x)+1}-0\right|\le |x-0| $$
Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ and $\delta=\epsilon$, then 
$$ \left|\frac{x}{\sin^2(x)+1}-0\right|\lt \epsilon \quad \mbox{whenever} \quad 0\lt\left|x-0\right|\lt\delta$$
Therefore
$$ \left|\frac{x}{\sin^2(x)+1}-0\right|\le |x-0|\lt \delta=\epsilon $$
And
by definition 
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin^2(x)+1} =0 $$